# Why does the assigned data do not change to the assigned value in the template immediately?

Tags: php, smarty

I have a smarty project:
The php file is like this:

```
<?php

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/smartyHeader.php');

$smarty->assign('foo', 'Foo');

if( isset($_GET['username'])) {

    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $smarty->assign('bar', $username);
}


$smarty->display('php/test.tpl');
```

In its corresponding template:

```
<form method="get" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}">
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

{if isset($bar)}
    bar {$bar}
{/if}
```

You see I use a form to submit the `username`.

However, it seems that `$smarty->assign('bar', $username);` is not executed in the php file. The username field is filled before form submission.

---

**EDIT-01**

my snapshot:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I am not sure whether the send username is assigned in the php file to `bar`, but the `12ewf` is my set last time. this time username `123` submit, the template do not change immediately.

the `Array` is my `print_r $_GET` test in :

```
if( isset($_GET['username'])) {

    print_r($_GET);
    ...
```

---

**EDIT-02**

See this:

```
if( isset($_GET['username'])) {

    print_r($_GET);

    echo $_GET['username'];

    $username = $_GET['username'];

    $smarty->assign('bar', $username);

}
```

the result in the browser:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

After several seconds when I refresh the page the value will change to the sent value, whether this is caused by the cache?

Comment: after submit form, can you please check your url ? is there username in url ?

Comment: @ashishkumar Yes, the username is in the url.

Comment: please try this one print_r($_GET). now let me know how many values are there

Comment: @ashishkumar See my edit-01, bro.

Comment: now try echo $_GET['username']

Comment: @ashishkumar See my edit-02.

Comment: I don't know whether this is caused by the cache, after several seconds I refresh the browser page, it will shows the correct value.

Comment: Try $smarty->caching = false; See https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/caching.tpl for more information on Smarty caching